# Are typed literals "tricky" in RDF4J?

Tags: sparql, rdf4j

In RDF, I can have an entity that is bound by a single property to multiple literal values.  Those values can also be typed to add clarity.

```
:dumpTruck :weight "heavy"^^xsd:string .
:dumpTruck :weight "36000"^^xsd:integer .
```

In SPARQL, I can query for just they type I want

```
SELECT  ?w
WHERE
  { :dumpTruck  :weight  ?w
    FILTER ( datatype(?w) = xsd:integer )
  }
```

Is there something like [getStatement](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/1.0/org/eclipse/rdf4j/repository/util/Connections.html#getStatement-org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryConnection-org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Resource-org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.IRI-org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Value-org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Resource...-) in RDF4J that can be constrained by datatype like that?

Comment: No, there isn't as it is for remote repositories this would need too much effort in providing query templates. - even not for the in-memory model. But you could write your own utility class that provides those convenience methods.

Comment: like running `getStatement`, then string-splitting the statement objects on `^^xsd:`, and then `grep`ing for my desired xsd type in chunk 2 of the split array?

Comment: Sometimes, just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you *should* do it. Better overall results would come from  `{ :dumpTruck :weightClass "heavy"^^xsd:string ; :weightKilograms "36000"^^xsd:integer . }`. `:weightClass` even becomes inferrable from `:weightKilograms` values.

Comment: @TallTed...  right, that was exactly what I was trying to avoid!  Sorry, should have added that to the question.  If possible, I'd like to stick to realist/BFO principles.  I may just go with scalar values specifications http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/OBI?iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OBI_0001931 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no a priori constraint possible, but you can post-process your result to filter on the datatype. For example you could use something along these lines (untested but you get the drift hopefully):

```java
QueryResults.stream(conn.getStatements(dumptruck, weight, null))
            .filter(s -> ((Literal)s.getObject()).getDatatype().equals(XMLSchema.INTEGER))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or alternatively, stick in a `Model` first and then filter:

```java
Model m = QueryResults.asModel(conn.getStatements(dumptruck, weight, null));
List intValues = Models.objectLiterals(m).stream().filter(l -> l.getDatatype().equals(XMLSchema.INTEGER)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm sure there's a couple of other/handier shortcuts available that I haven't thought of. The [RDF4J docs](http://docs.rdf4j.org/) have tutorials and examples to spare, however.