# Convert RDF4J stream filter (lambda?) from Java to Scala

Tags: scala, rdf4j

A follow-up to [Are typed literals "tricky" in RDF4J?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308356/are-typed-literals-tricky-in-rdf4j)

I have some triples abut the weight of dump trucks, using literal objects with different data types.  I'm only interested in the integer values, so I want to filter based on the data type.  Jeen Broekstra sent a Java solution about a week ago, and I'm having trouble converting it into Scala, my team's preferred language.

This is what I have so far.  Eclipse is complaining

> not found: value l

```
val rdf4jServer = "http://host.domain:7200"
val repositoryID = "trucks"
val MyRepo = new HTTPRepository(rdf4jServer, repositoryID)
MyRepo.initialize()
var con = MyRepo.getConnection()

val f = MyRepo.getValueFactory()
val DumpTruck = f.createIRI("http://example.com/dumpTruck")
val Weight = f.createIRI("http://example.com/weight")    
val m = QueryResults.asModel(con.getStatements(DumpTruck, Weight, null))
val intValuesStream = Models.objectLiterals(m).stream()

# OK up to here
# errors start below

val intValuesFiltered = 
  intValuesStream.filter(l -> l.getDatatype().equals(XMLSchema.INTEGER))
val intValues = intValuesFiltered.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: You can also avoid using the `=>` in your case, i.e. `filter(_.getDatatype().equals(XMLSchema.INTEGER))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `->` with `=>`:

```
val intValuesFiltered = intValuesStream.filter(l => l.getDatatype().equals(XMLSchema.INTEGER))
```